# Resolução de 176px não compatibiliza com Media Queries

Tags: css3, media-queries

Estou usando estes exemplos de media Queries abaixo,mais ao testar a resolução em celulares de 176 pixels não tem efeito algum, quais são as propriedades certas para isso?

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) { }
@media screen and (min-width:480px) { }
@media screen and (min-width:600px) { }
@media screen and (min-width:768px) { }
@media screen and (min-width:992px) { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seguindo a lógica que você usou, nenhuma dessas regras se aplica a uma tela de 176px de largura.

Veja que você usa o `min-width`. Ou seja, o CSS só será aplicado se a largura for igual ou maior ao valor informado.

Você tem duas opções: criar uma nova regra:

```
@media screen and (min-width:176px) { }
```

Ou alterar a primeira regra usando `max-width`:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) { }
```

Comment: Passou despercebido, muito obrigado